# Using the same file for stdin and stdout with redirection

Tags: unix, pipe

I'm writing a application that acts like a filter: it reads input from a file (stdin), processes, and write output to another file (stdout). The input file is completely read before the application starts to write the output file.

Since I'm using stdin and stdout, I can run is like this:

```
$ ./myprog <file1.txt >file2.txt
```

It works fine, but if I try to use the same file as input and output (that is: read from a file, and write to the same file), like this:

```
$ ./myprog <file.txt >file.txt
```

it cleans `file.txt` before the program has the chance to read it.

Is there any way I can do something like this in a command line in Unix?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The shell is what clobbers your output file, as it's preparing the output filehandles *before* executing your program.  There's no way to make your program read the input before the shell clobbers the file in a single shell command line.

You need to use two commands, either moving or copying the file before reading it:

```
mv file.txt filecopy.txt
./myprog < filecopy.txt > file.txt
```

Or else outputting to a copy and then replacing the original:

```
./myprog < file.txt > filecopy.txt
mv filecopy.txt file.txt
```

If you can't do that, then you need to pass the filename to your program, which opens the file in read/write mode, and handles all the I/O internally.

```
./myprog file.txt                 # reads and writes according to its own rules
```

Answer (score 19):

There's a sponge utility in [moreutils](http://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/) package:

```
./myprog < file.txt | sponge file.txt
```

To quote the manual:

> Sponge  reads  standard input and writes it out to the specified file. Unlike a shell redirect, sponge soaks up all its input before opening the output file. This  allows  constructing  pipelines that read from and write to the same file.

Comment: Please, elaborate your answer.

Answer (score 8):

For a solution of a purely academic nature:

```
$ ( unlink file.txt && ./myprog >file.txt ) <file.txt
```

Possibly problematic side-effects are:

- If `./myprog` fails, you destroy your input.  (Naturally...)
- `./myprog` runs from a subshell (Use `{ ... ; }` instead of `( ... )` to avoid.)
- `file.txt` becomes a *new file* with a new inode and file permissions.
- You need `+w` permission on the directory housing `file.txt`.

Comment: Strange. Why doesn't `$ (./myprog >file.txt) <file.txt` work while removing `file.txt` first works?

Comment: Your example does that because `>file.txt` truncates the contents of file.txt and this is incidentally the same file that `<file.txt` is reading from.  (This is mentioned in the original question and in the accepted answer, and using a sub-shell doesn't change this.)  By unlinking first, `>file.txt` creates a *new file* (different inode at the same path) that is separate from what `<file.txt` is reading from.

Comment: So all we have to do is to run the sub-shell ourselves.  I think I know the answer, but I'm still not sure why...